# Samsung Fame GT S6812 Call Recorder Not working

Tags: samsung-mobile

I am using samsung fame, this phone actually without java.
I want to record my calls, for that I used almost all applications in google play. But calls are not recording properly.
Its recording like noice. example if u ever fast forward song in type-recorder how that sound  to here same like that calls are recording.

Is there any solution/app. I need to record important calls.

Please give me the solution.

**Note: Jelly Bean 4.1.2, No java.
Few apps are showing message something like call recording not started, Java not started.**